# Как в WPF убрать стандартные кнопки в модальном окне?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel

При клике на кнопку у меня появляется модальное окно, вот такого вида[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как убрать две нижние кнопки(желтые), пользуюсь фреймверком Catel.
Создал окно с помощью сервиса UIVisualizerService.

Пример модели:

```
public Command ShowCommand
{
    get
    {
       return new Command(() =>
       {
            var viewModel = new CalcViewModel();
            var dependencyResolve = this.GetDependencyResolver();
            var uiVisualizerService = dependencyResolve.Resolve<UIVisualizerService>();
            uiVisualizerService.ShowDialog(viewModel);
        });
    }
}
```

Модель модального окна пустая.

Comment: как вариант в свойства ненужных кнопок прописать `Hidden`

Comment: этих кнопок нету в коде xaml, как я понимаю они генерируются при компиляции, даже если представление будет пустое, без кода, эти кнопки все равно отображаются

Comment: Ну это вопрос к знатокам Catel, сам по себе WPF кнопки не добавляет.

Comment: по-хорошему вам надо изменить в заголовке вопроса WPF на Catel, т.к. @VladD уже заметил вам, что эти кнопки создает не WPF, а ваш фреймворк. На Catel же есть документация, что там пишут по этому поводу?